# String errors in convertor

Tags: java, string, char

so my code works for some words but not others it sprints out String index out of range: -1 
im suppose to print out ub before every vowel and vowel cluster 
ex  dubious would be dubububious or cat loveo would be lubovudeo

String sentance, set;

```
        sentance = "toster iooppp";
        set= translate(sentance);
        System.out.println(set);
}
public static String translate (String sentence){

    String set = " ";
    sentence= sentence.toLowerCase();
    scan = new Scanner (sentence);

    while (scan.hasNext()) {

        set+= toUbbi (scan.next());
        set += " "; 
    }
    return  set; 
    }

 private static String toUbbi(String word ) {
    String str= word;
    String new_str="";
     for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            if (isVowel(c) && isVowel(str.charAt(i -1)) )
            { // If is a vowel
                new_str += "ub" ;
            }
            new_str += c;
        }
     return new_str;
    }


    private static boolean isVowel(char c)
    {
        if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u' ){
            return true;}

        return false;
```

Comment: This code is not complete - there are lines missing at both sides.

Comment: Wouldn't cat loveo be lubovububeo?

Comment: I suspect your logic is incorrect, and you'll probably find that it's giving you the wrong answer when you get it not to crash.  I'd step through it by hand and see how `toUbbi` is going to work.  Also make sure that the logic does what you want at the boundaries, i.e. when `i` is 0 and when it's `str.length()-1`.

Answer (score 0):

in first iteration it gives error..

```
        if (isVowel(c) && isVowel(str.charAt(i -1)) )
        { // If is a vowel
            new_str += "ub" ;
        }
```

so change like this..

```
        if (isVowel(c))
        { // If is a vowel
            new_str += "ub" ;
        }
```

or change your loop..

```
  for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
      // yur remain code...
  }
```